# ScrollIntoView behavior smooth is broken in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with multiple rows, each row has a button and on clicking of any of those button i want it to scroll to top and some how i have achieved it but the scroll is not smooth, its directly jumping on that div, i've used multiple npm libraries, polyfill(suggested by chrome team on github issues), used window object, tried changing in `chrome://flags`(enabling smooth scroll) but any of that is not working...
if i'm using it without `({behavior: "smooth"})`, it directly jumps on it and when i use `({behavior: "smooth"})` it broken like scrolling to top(like for 1mm) for like 100ms and then stops like a lag.

PLEASE HELP!!!

```
smoothscroll.polyfill();

const top = useRef();
const Component=()=>{
  const scrollToTop = () => {
    top.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };

  const list=()=> (
    data.map((item)=> {
      return(
        <Row>
          <Column>
            {data.id}
          </Column>
          <Column>
            {data.name}
          </Column>
          <Column>
            {data.section}
          </Column>
          <Column>
            <button onClick={()=>scrollToTop()}>
              manage
            <button>
          </Column>
        </Row>
      );
    });
  )

  return (
    <div ref="top"/>
    {list()}
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a Chromium issue. I have the same problem within an Angular component, but only in Chrome and Edge.. Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 6):

I'd prefer @Partha Roy solution myself, but if you like more control, use [window.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)

Try this:

```js
const App = () => {
  
  const elementRef = React.useRef(null)
  
  const toTop = () => {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }
  // If back to element (use Ref)
  const toElemnt = () => {
     if(!elementRef) return
    // Get element coords from Ref
    const element =
      elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY

    window.scroll({
      top: element,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="content" style={{ height: 1500 }}>Scroll Down <span>&#8595;</span>
      
        <div ref={elementRef} style={{ marginTop: 750 }}>
          Element - continue scrolling <span>&#8595;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
       <button onClick={toElemnt}>Back to Element <span>&#8593;</span></button>
      <button onClick={toTop}>Back to to <span>&#8593;</span></button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: when passing a ref around components in a context object, using ```window.scroll``` was the only solution that worked for me; passing in an options object broke scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use CSS option to set the scroll behavior across the app smooth.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ref` then assign it to the target element:

```
const top= useRef();
```

assign to this here:

```
return(
    <div ref={top}/>
    {list()}
);
```